# ASP.net Core Missing Copy xxxxx.resources.dll

Tags: asp.net-core-localization

I have a project named "Common". It contains resource.resx and resource.zh.resx resource files.  And I created an ASP.net core project and referenced Common project.  When I build the ASP.net core project I doesn't see Common.resource in output folder "bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\zh" but the common.dll already included bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0.  Anyone can tell me how can I do.

Comment: Check where is the build output of your common project for debug configuration https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Since non-core project will auto copy it to destination folder why ASP.net core need to manual copy with script.  Is it a bug?